# vue-test-utils & jest: How To Test Single File Component Filter?

Tags: vuejs2

I have a Single File Component with a filter defined

```
filters: {
  capitalize: function (value) {
    if (!value) return ''
    value = value.toString()
    return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)
  }
},
```

I thought I could simply test it like

```
it('should capitalize input', () => {
  const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComp)
  expect(wrapper.vm.capitalize('foo')).toEqual('Foo')
  // or
  expect(wrapper.vm.filters.capitalize('foo')).toEqual('Foo')
})
```

but apparently I can't access a filter function like that directly and for some reason I cannot find in the docs how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access Vue filters using:

`Vue.$options.filters.capitalize()`

Comment: You can also access local filters using: 
```wrapper.vm.$options.filters```